# How to implement admob rewarded video ads in a list view?

Tags: java, android, admob, rewardedvideoad

I want to know how to implement AdMob rewarded video ads in a list view?
I'm using the source code from [here](https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/tree/master/Android)

and I want to use it in this class StickerPackDetailsActivity.java
and the layout is gonna like this

![layout][1]

I want to lock add to WhatsApp and unlock it by watching video reward.
but this stickerdetails showed from listview from

![here][2]

so, how to implement video reward ads only in 1 specified item of the listview not all of them?

Comment: As I have created [StickerApp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wastickers.apps.gujarati.stickers.pack) I think you have to check params of `identifier` in `Detail Activity` and load Rewarded Ads.

Comment: @PratikButani the identifier is in here [link](https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/blob/master/Android/app/src/main/java/com/example/samplestickerapp/StickerPackDetailsActivity.java) and here [link](https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/blob/master/Android/app/src/main/java/com/example/samplestickerapp/StickerPack.java) , can you tell me what to do and how to implement it?

Comment: This [line](https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/blob/master/Android/app/src/main/java/com/example/samplestickerapp/StickerPackDetailsActivity.java#L77) is getting name of sticker pack which is passed same way you can get id of sticker pack and check with your constant ID in which you want to show ads.

Comment: @PratikButani thanks for the logic.. I got it and done.. big thanks

Comment: @DanyHermawan Can you provide the solution please?

Answer (score -2):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RewardedVideoAdListener {
private RewardedVideoAd mRewardedVideoAd;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




        MobileAds.initialize(this,"ca-app-pub111111111");
        mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);

listitem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             loadRewardedVideoAd(); 
            }
        });

}

    private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-",
                new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }


    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
         loadRewardedVideoAd();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
       mRewardedVideoAd.pause(this);
       super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        mRewardedVideoAd.resume(this);
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Comment: that's the basic implementation for RewardedVideo Ads... I want to know how to add it into listview and only in 1 specified item

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for participating but please read our https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. Answers constisting purely of code and no explanation at all, are of poor quality since it doesn't help much in learning and understanding. Please try to read the article and use it to improve your future answers.